# libroscpp.so No such files or Directory in ECLIPSE

Tags: ros

I am trying to load the library `libroscpp.so`

I am using `Eclipse 4.16.0` and I want `ROS` libraries to load from Eclipse when i execute the project.

Below is the error i am getting when i execute my Application from ECLIPSE.

`/home/ams_user/work/vijay/MyProj/objs/MyApp: error while loading shared libraries: libroscpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

However, i am successful in loading from Terminal using `ldconfig` command.

Any setting in eclipse where i can give the library path.. Kindly suggest..

Tried adding below as below :

select Run --> Run configurations... --> C/C++ Application (double click or click on New). Select the correct binary on the main tab (Search project should work when your binary was already built). Then in the environment tab, added

```
Name : ROS_ROOT
Value : /opt/ros/melodic/share/ros

Name : ROS_LIB (Name i chosen)
Value : /opt/ros/melodic/lib/   <-- This is where my lib is located.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved as below : Right click on the project, --> select the executable file --> select Run --> Run configurations... --> C/C++ Application . Then in the environment tab, add as below :

```
    ---------------
    Variable⇒LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    Value ⇒/opt/ros/melodic/lib/
    --------------
```